# How to show Map with multiple annotation in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, dictionary, mapkit

I have UITableViewController and inside my cell i need to display map with multiple annotations.

I need to show map on my tableview cell and plot multiple annotation in  that map also.
Something like this [Screenshot](http://s30.postimg.org/qah5vqibl/Screen_Shot_2015_09_14_at_8_57_28_pm.png)

I searched in google and couldnt get that much help.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need interaction with the map (scroll, zoom etc) you can use MKMapSnapshotter. It generates a snapshot image of the map and requires much less memory than actually using a map view. A useful link is this: [http://nshipster.com/mktileoverlay-mkmapsnapshotter-mkdirections/](http://Tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Another option when interaction isn't needed is the [MapboxStatic](https://github.com/mapbox/mapboxstatic.swift) library, which gives PNG or JPEG images of maps, which is ideal for table view usage.